# Unable to authorize dropbox api in wordrpess

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, curl, dropbox

Using the plugin, dropbox media importer in a wordpress app. I add the client key and secret after creating a personal dropbox app with full dropbox permission, I attempt to authorize the request but it returns an error that says invalided `client_id or secret`. When I try to do the curl request with the `client_id & secret` I get the same response.

**Request:**

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/auth/token/from_oauth1 \
--header "Authorization: Basic <REDACTED>" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data "{\"oauth1_token\": \"qievr8hamyg6ndck\",\"oauth1_token_secret\": \"qomoftv0472git7\"}"
```

**Response:**

```
{"error_summary": "invalid_oauth1_token_info/", "error": {".tag": "invalid_oauth1_token_info"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [/2/auth/token/from_oauth1](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) endpoint you're attempting to use is only for exchanging existing OAuth 1 access tokens (e.g., as previously retrieved for use with the now-retired Dropbox API v1) for OAuth 2 access tokens.

If you're just integrating now, you wouldn't have any OAuth 1 access tokens, and so shouldn't be using this endpoint. (Accordingly, it's indicating that the `oauth1_token` and `oauth1_token_secret` values you're supplying are incorrect; the ones you're using are just copied from the documentation, but you would need to supply your real values.)

Instead, you should implement the Dropbox OAuth 2 app authorization flow. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization) and [guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide).

Comment: I’ve added my own Id and secret while testing the request. But, just posted the documentation keys over here.

Comment: It sounds like you may have put your "app key and secret" in place of the "OAuth 1 access token". These are not the same thing though, and cannot be used interchangably. It sounds like you don't actually need to be using /2/auth/token/from_oauth1, and should implement the OAuth 2 flow instead.